# 405 Error when trying to POST a file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, paperclip, http-status-code-405

I am using paperclip gem to upload a file to the database. When I select the file I want to upload and go to create it, the next page should redirect_to root path. Instead, I get "Method Not Allowed" in my browser. I open Dev Tools and the console says:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
My logs look like:

```
Started POST "/assets" for ::1 at 2015-08-20 10:41:11 -0400
```

and remains hooked until I go back to another page.

Here is my controller

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
# before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index 
 @assets = current_user.assets      
end

def show 
 @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id]) 
end

def new
 @asset = current_user.assets.build
end

def create 
 @asset = current_user.assets.build(asset_params) 
  if @asset.save
   flash[:success] = "The file was uploaded!"
   redirect_to root_path
  else
   render 'new'
 end
end

def edit 
 @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id]) 
end

def update 
 @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id]) 
end

def destroy 
 @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id]) 
end

private

def asset_params
 params.require(:asset).permit(:uploaded_file)

 end
end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

has_attached_file :uploaded_file

validates_attachment_presence :uploaded_file
validates_attachment_size :uploaded_file, less_than: 10.megabytes   
end
```

And I am using the simple_form gem to submit the file:

```
<%= simple_form_for @asset, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %> 
 <% if @asset.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
   <% @asset.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|%>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
   </ul> 
 <% end %>
<% end %>
<p> 
<%= f.input :uploaded_file %> 
</p> 
<p>
<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</p> 
<% end %>
```

The 405 error indicates that I am doing a request not supported by the Asset model. I have resources :assets in my config routes file and when I run rake routes, all of my RESTful routes are there.

I would appreciate any help on this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my attention is that you have a route at /assets, which is normally reserved to the Rails [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). Rails is known to be not very informative about reporting problems with this (see [issue 10132](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10132) and [issue 19996](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19996) on rails core).

Try moving your asset pipeline to another mount point, and see if that fixes your problem. This can be accomplished by setting Rails.application.config.assets.prefix to something other than /assets. For example in config/initializers/assets.rb add the line:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = '/pipeline_assets'
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. After reading a little more about assets, I think the configuration shouldn't go into application.rb, but rather into config/initializers/assets.rb, so I've updated the answer accordingly. It shouldn't matter a lot, but I believe that's more in line with Rails conventions.